# Where can I get dragon bones and scales without killing dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 100 smithing. I need more dragon bones and dragon scales, but I can't find any dragons anywhere. Is there any way I can get them without killing dragons?

Comment: Are there any soy-based alternatives?

Answer (score 16):

No, killing dragons is the only source of dragon bones and dragon scales. If you roam around the world enough you'll find dragons, there are unlimited dragons available to spawn according to Todd Howard, the director.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant face one alone. I'm not a high enough level.

Comment: Curious, how can you haver 100 smithing and still not be high enough level to kill a dragon by yourself? I've killed dragons solo as low as level 5 before.

Comment: Sure but you can have 100 smithing without leveling a single combat skill. Maybe he's trying to make a specialized character of some sort.

Comment: with 100 smithing you should be able to improve any armor to make dragon damage minimal. Maybe you need an inbetween armor to help you fight dragons before you get bones and scales.

Comment: @Nobody turn the difficulty down when you go dragon hunting then.

Comment: one important aspect to remember, random dragon encounters do not occur while travelling the roads. get off the beaten path. go climb some mountains, dude. Thar be dragons, argh!

Comment: A tip for help against dragons is to get the Spellbreaker shield (which has a ward when blocing, which I've found is quite good). or at least good enough against the dragons I'm meeting at lvl 59. I't sobtained from a quest http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spellbreaker

Comment: @Josh, that's not true. Dragon encounters can and do occur while traveling the roads.

Answer (score 7):

To find dragons, you need to do some main quest missions.

Killing the dragon in the tower is enough. You can also try to go to dragon stones, or do a lot of teleports to villages and towns, as dragons usually appear when you teleport (higher chance than normal to appear. but not much (not confirmed)).

You don't need to kill many dragons for the armor because one dragon gives enough materials for one equipment piece.

Comment: I've stored every dragon bone and scale from every dragon I fragged in my Breeze home in Whiterun. But I haven't done much smithing. I plan to at some point.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can get bones without killing a dragon, but there is one place where you can get scales.  On the hill north/northeast of Rorikstead, there is a shrine to Akatosh that has a few "offerings" lying around it.  One of these is a dragon scale.  If you leave the area and wait for 10 days, the items will all respawn, meaning it is possible to craft and upgrade a full dragonscale set before doing the Dragon Rising part of the main quest. If you have the Dawn
Guard DLC you will find one dragon bone in the laboratory of Serana's mother.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to find dragons, if you haven't already, is to find the Dragon Shout Stones all over. Normally, I find a dragon at any one of them. Also if you want a weapon that will help even at your level(Mehrunes' Razor: slight (10%)* chance to instantly kill; even dragons, I've done it), go to Dawnstar and complete the mission given. You will be asked to kill him later, and after you do, Mehrune fixes his dagger and gives it to you. Just be careful, he also sends two Deadric Warriors after you.

by: link23454

Comment: Note that you can't do Mehrunes Dagon's quest until level 20, by which point you should at least have a fighting chance against dragons anyhow.

Comment: and mehrune's razor chance is more like 2.5-3% instead of 10%

Answer (score 0):

Just fast travel to any of the dragon head symbolson the map and even after you killed the dragon there another dragon will spawn there and the loot should have respawned as well :)